# How to load/unload assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm working on a C# solution, and I need to compile a project in the solution, load its assemblies and explore its types.

My problem is, once I load the assembly, I can't unload it, so I'm forced to close VS and reopen it if I want to recompile the project whose assembly I'm exploring. I've read that loading the assembly in a different AppDomain can solve my problem, but with that I lose the LoadFrom method and I'm interested in automatically loading dependencies.

So, my question is: how can I load an assembly with its dependencies, explore its types and then unload it?

Comment: Why do you lose the `LoadFrom` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it the ugly way: copying the assembly file to a temporary folder and opening it from there. That way I can explore it without keeping the original assembly open and throwing errors all around when trying to recompile.

Thanks to everyone for taking time to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to explore it without being able to execute something, you can use a third party like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) to read your assembly as data.

Answer (score 0):

I do recommended https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib which is much powerful to compile or decompile or u can use dnspy https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy